# Adding PostgreSQL data source to excel didn't ask for credentials other than server IP and database

Tags: postgresql, connections, excel

I saw Excel supported using PostgreSQL as a data source. I'm used to using ODBC connections for Access so having direct Postgres support is exciting.

When connecting I entered the Server IP and database name, selected my table, and data was pulled in. No Username, no password. Do I have some gaping security hole on my database? Shouldn't there be some sort of authentication?

I have an ODBC DSN for that server configured on this workstation and has set up a workbook using that DSN just a few minutes previously (which oddly enough requires a username and password even though the credentials are in the DSN)but I don't think that should be relevant.

Comment: I think you answered your own question: _"the credentials are in the DSN"_.

Comment: When checking "Existing Connections" in excel I had previously configured a connection  file for that database and forgotten about it. Could that be making it so I don't need to enter credentials?

Comment: @mustaccio But I'm not using an ODBC Connection. I'm selecting Get Data > From Database > PostgreSQL. Its a completely different driver too.

When I tried setting up an ODBC connection it was asking users for a username and password when they launched the workbook for the first time which is a pain since it's already in the DSN so I was looking for alternative options where the credentials could somehow be saved within the workbook.